# Menu dinâmico ASP.NET MVC

Tags: mvc

Sou novo em MVC e preciso fazer um menu dinâmico, mas não acho solução (web forms era mais fácil rs). Tenho 3 models (Menu, SubMenu1 e SubMenu2) preciso percorrer esses objetos e ir montando o html na view, mas a view tipada só aceita um objeto e mesmo se eu fizer com ViewBag não dá certo por que tenho que percorrer o Submenu1 com o id do Menu e o SubMenu2 com id do SubMenu1, com webform eu percorria os objetos e jogava numa stringbuilder e depois no ASPX eu jogava a stringbuilder numa label, mas com mvc estou um pouco perdido, alguém tem idéia de como fazer isso em mvc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

achei uma solução da seguinte maneira:

Li meus objetos com foreach e fui montando o html do menu numa StringBuilder, passei a StringBuilder para uma viewbag. Na view li a viewbag assim: @MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewBag.Menu) e deu certo!

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, o objeto `Menu` deveria ser o pai de `SubMenu1` e `SubMenu2`. Acredito que talvez essa ainda não seja a melhor abordagem, mas isso fica por sua conta. Se o objeto `Menu` for o objetop pai, pode passar ele para a `view` como o tipo padrão, e acessar os submenus como propriedades desse objeto.